# For food photography with a Macro lens do I have to get a particular size of dishes?

Tags: macro, food-photography, still-life

From Rfusca's comment here: [Why isn't the background towel visible in this still life?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/22181/5205)

> She might have used a macro lens, but this definitely isn't a macro shot. Its not nearly 1:1 unless those are the smallest glasses ever,

I am about to get a reversing ring.
If I want to get the whole two vessels in the scene, and also wish to show every detail of the food, then will the normal serving dishes do, or I have to get some "tiniest" dishes?

Or
I have understood his point wrong?

Comment: If you put a reversal ring on most standard range lenses, there'll be no getting two of any dish in focus...your depth of field is shockingly short and so is your focus distance.  Again, you don't *need* macro for food photography.

Comment: @rfusca You never replied to the previous comment. How would I then get the "details" of the food? the texture? I have 1.8G 50mm.

Comment: By coincidence, I took a macro photograph of a head of garlic tonight: http://www.flickr.com/photos/coneslayer/6909289932/lightbox/ Is this what you have in mind? If not, you're not talking about macro. A place setting or a bowl of food or a glass of water is not macro photography.

Comment: @Anisha, the best way to show texture is through the lighting.

Comment: @coneslayer No, I don't have that in mind. the reason for purchasing the macro, is that I want the food "texture" to be shown "clearly".

Comment: @rfusca And macro lens won't be an added advantage to the texture (in the way I am looking for)?

Comment: Its an advantage in that you can get as close as you'd like, easily.  If you want to get right on top of the food, you can.  BUt you don't need to be 2 inches from a dish to show its texture.

Comment: @rfusca Okay, so conclusion is that I have set up light properly to show texture, macro won't help when I want the two dishes in the scene?

Comment: Lighting helps to show texture, yes.  A macro lens won't help you get two dishes in the scene..no.  Feel free to pop into chat.

Comment: @rfusca Then why would she had taken that photo with 100m macro? (other thread linked in the question) OR should this be a new question? OR if you aren't going to anwer just tell me so that I don't ask again.

Comment: A few reasons, most probably because its a great lens - razor sharp, low distortion, and can do very short DOF.  Plus, she *can* get really, really close **if** she wants to.  A reversal ring will not mimick this flexibility.

Comment: @AnishaKaul One more thing I would like to point out. Reverse Ring is just a cheap alternative and is nowhere near an actual macro lens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shoot food photos with a macro lens.  However I am usually a meter or more away from the food.  So I am using the lens like a portrait lens.  Many food photographers would probably use a 70-200mm lens - you can get a shallow depth of field, but not like true macro, where the lens is virtually touching your subject and the depth of field is a mm or two.

If you use a reversing ring, that is completely different than a macro lens. With a macro lens you can back up from the food and frame it any way you like.  But with a reversing ring, you will not be able to control focus with the lens.  You will have to move the camera towards the food until it is in focus, and you will be very close.  Again imagine your lens almost touching the food.

In the image you referenced, the camera was probably as much as a meter away from the subject, not a matter of a few cms.  So yes, she used a macro lens, but it's not a macro shot.  Reversing rings are not what you want for food.  You want something between normal and moderate telephoto (50mm to 200mm).  The macro lens she used is 100mm, so in the middle of that range.

Comment: You shoot with a macro lens because its a good lens, sharp, etc....not because you need the *macro* aspect, thats what I've been trying to say.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I have the 50mm 1.8F G prime lens. Hope that'll be helpful.

Comment: Anisha, that lens is fine for starting food photography. Smitten Kitchen uses it a lot, and she has some great photos.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Alright, thanks, now I have to figure out where to get the sunlight! Have grills on windows.

Comment: Take the food outside?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Yes, taking the food to the "park"! But, that'll make me look like a fool for sure. :)

Comment: Who cares? Sometimes you have to look like a fool to get The Shot. :)

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Actually, if you ever come to India, you won't find any Indian photographers with cameras hanging on the necks.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't - well, not in the sense that you're asking.

That wasn't the point of the comment.

The comment was to indicate that the shot wasn't taken at 1:1 magnification (which is what a macro shot is) - because the objects in the picture are clearly larger than the camera sensor.  You'd need dishes the size of thimbles.  The comment was intended to help you realize that a macro lens may *help* with food photography by not limiting your focusing distance, but its not *required* nor do many food shots end up being *macro shots*.